# How to export local service to server with a public domain?

Tags: ssh, debian, tunneling

I am pretty new to this. But I have two devices, both running debian. One is a school server (with public domain), where I don't have root access. Second is a virtualmachine with bridged adapter to local network. Running a nginx website on `localhost:80`. I want to access the website from the `public_domain.com:8080`.

When I tried to port forward to the server. I figured out that the `GatewayForwarding` is not enabled and I don't have persmissions to change it.
I tried:

```
ssh -R 8080:localhost:80 -g name@server -N 
ssh -R 0.0.0.0:8080:localhost:80 -g name@server -N
```

when I netstat on the server I get back column `Local address  127.0.0.1:8080`
and
`curl localhost:8080`
works fine, but when I try to do `public_domain.com:8080` I get empty response back.

Is there any other way how to accomplish "exporting" the local service to the public domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the output of `netstat` shows you something like this...

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

...then you have found your problem; a socket bound to the localhost address (`127.0.0.1`) isn't going to be accessible from anywhere other than the local system. According to the `sshd` man page:

> By default, TCP listening sockets on the server will be bound to the loopback interface only. This may be overridden by specifying a bind_address. An empty bind_address, or the address `*`, indicates that the remote socket should listen on all interfaces. **Specifying a remote bind_address will only succeed if the server's GatewayPorts option is enabled (see sshd_config(5)).**

I've emphasized the key bit: unless `GatewayPorts` is enabled in the remote *server* configuration, your forwarded ports will always bind to `localhost`.

---

You can of course trivially work around this by running a simple tcp proxy on the server that listens on `<the public address>:8080` and forwards the connections to `127.0.0.1:8080`.  For example, using `socat`:

```
socat tcp-listen:8080,fork,bind=1.2.3.4 tcp:localhost:8080
```

(Replace `1.2.3.4` with the public address of the remote host.)

You could just execute the proxy command as part of your `ssh` command:

```
ssh -R 8080:localhost:80 -g name@server \
  socat tcp-listen:8080,fork,bind=1.2.3.4 tcp:localhost:8080
```

If `socat` isn't installed on the remote server, you can just install it into your home directory.